# ASP.NET MVC | Two Actions one View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have two actions Start and Question. And I have two views "Start" and "Question". I am would like to continue use action Start with view "Start" and action Question with view "Question", and I want to use one view name in URL for both controllers, this name is Question. It should be like /Controller_Name/Question. How to do this?

**UPD**. Guys, I am sorry for bad explanation.

Comment: Do you have **two controllers** or do you have **two controller actions in one controller**?

Comment: yes, you are right, It is my mistake. I have two controller actions in one controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is slightly vague but would having one view (Question) and calling a partial (@Html.Partial) which returns the "Start" partial work for you?

Comment: I can do it, but my action will be twice bigger.

Comment: I rethink your advice. It is good. Action will not be twice bigger, and possible I will implement this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your clearly, because Controller does not related to view, may be you mean Actionresult or you mean folder which related to Controller.

Method view could take parameter = viewname, in your actions methods you could write:

```
public ActionResult Start()
{
    return View("Start");
}

public ActionResult Question()
{
    return View("Start")
}
```

both methods will render Start.aspx(or cshtml if u using Razor) View

Comment: He said he wants Question view with both not Start. ;)

Comment: Maybe not the answer to Sergii's question, but to mine :)